# Why am I not getting the correct output in ques of printing even and odd index character seperatly?

Tags: java

[enter link description here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem)

This is the link to the question. I have written this code in java but I am not getting the correct output.Why?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            String even="";
            String odd ="";
            for(int j=0; j<name.length(); j++)
            {
                if(j%2==0)
                    even=even+String.valueOf(name.charAt(j));
                else
                    odd=odd+String.valueOf(name.charAt(j));
            }
            System.out.println(even+" "+odd);
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Input (stdin)
    2
    Hacker
    Rank

Your Output (stdout)

    // a blank space here.
    Hce akr

Expected Output

    Hce akr
    Rn ak
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `int n = sc.nextInt();` consumes the integer that's input (2), but there is a still a newline.

When your loop goes through the first time, and you call `String name = sc.nextLine();`, it will consume that remaining newline (and nothing else). Hence, your blank line.

To get past that, make sure to read in the new line after you read in `n`

Also, the last entry isn't shown because you likely need a trailing newline (one after "Rank" in your input)

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but the problem is in your input taking.
if u take this as a input
2
Hacker
Rank
then your excepted output never come as u mentioned in your question.
Now i tell u in brief about where is the problem:---------

int n = sc.nextInt();
here u take integer input 2 but you delare only one string type variable.u must declare 2string typr variable if u choose 2.
otherwise only 1 tring willl be handled .

Hacker
Rank
thatswhy u take 2 string variable bt according to ur code only hacker will be compiled and give the output.
u declare 2 string variable .